# Create a polygon from multiline offset

Tags: postgis, polygon, line, polygonize

I've a multiline in Postgis.

The multiline represents a wall, and I need to transform it to a polygon given the thickness of the wall itself, so I need to create offset lines, join them and create the polygon.

In practice, I need to retrieve the yellow polygon from the black line and the thickness as numeric value:

[image]

How can I obtain the polygon?

From a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455274/offset-curves-from-linestring-to-polygon-using-postgis-postgresql) I understand that I can obtain offset lines with a query similar to the following one:

```
SELECT 
f.gid,
ST_Union(
    ST_OffsetCurve(ST_LineMerge(f.geom), 6.0, 'quad_segs=4 join=round'),
    ST_OffsetCurve(ST_LineMerge(f.geom), -6.0, 'quad_segs=4 join=round')
    ) as track
FROM
wall f;
```

But I obtain only the parallel lines (the ones in brown):

[image]

Ho can I create the polygon from them?

If the implementation is simpler, it's not necessary the cap of the line in the first image, the cap itself can be zero like in the second one.

Comment: I think you are lookinng for [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) rather than ST_OffsetCurve, with  endcap=square. There are some good examples on that page.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça is likely right. If that works please self answer =)

Comment: Yes, it works. If you can set an answer with it I will accept it.